# Redirecting from child window to parent to a iframe using javascript (OAuth)

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe, oauth

Here is the ideal scenario We are shooting for:

1. Acme.com has a "My Account" link. When the user clicks on this link, the content comes from https://acme.xyz.com/myaccount and is displayed within an iframe on acme.com
2. I control the "acme.xyz.com" app and give the user the option of logging in with their Google/Facebook credentials. Since OAuth rightly frowns upon iframes during the login, I perform the OAuth redirect by opening a child window.
3. Once I get the OAuth callback from Google/Facebook in the child window, I'd like to close the child window and revert focus back to the parent window (the one within the iframe).

   How do I perform step #3? I realize I have to do this using javascript, but we threw our resident javascript guy under the bus and ran him over (grin). If someone could give me a snippet of js/jQuery code, then I promise to be kind to all javascript dudes.

I realize that pop-up blockers would create trouble with the above approach, anything else that may be problematic? mobile devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty straightforward - for anybody else looking for the solution, this is what I used:

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){

             if(opener) { // close OAuth popup window if applicable
                 opener.location.href="${customerHomeUrl}";
                 top.close();
             }

         });
    </script>
```